# How to get gluLookAt parameters out of a 4x4 matrix

Tags: opengl, matrix

Sorry in advance if this is a really basic Matrix/OpenGl question. I have a situation where I have a 4x4 matrix that I would like to translate to, but don't want to use glMultMatrixf. I would rather use a gluLookAt method I've been using for most other translations. Is getting the values needed from the 4x4 matrix as simple as just pulling out the proper column values? If so which columns map to which parameters?

The signature of gluLookAt:

```
void gluLookAt( GLdouble eyeX,
            GLdouble eyeY,
            GLdouble eyeZ,
            GLdouble centerX,
            GLdouble centerY,
            GLdouble centerZ,
            GLdouble upX,
            GLdouble upY,
            GLdouble upZ )
```

http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/ref/glu/lookat.html
http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluLookAt_code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters don't exist in the matrix, *per se*. The matrix is *calculated* from them. It's produced by multiplying the three vertexes (eye, center, and "up") into the current view matrix.

The OpenGL Red Book (which you really *should* get, if you don't have it already) explains it in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

check out the DirectX versions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee417299(VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee417302(VS.85).aspx

those explain how the look ats are made.

from that you should be able to reverse the process, or at least determine if it's possible.

What are you trying to do exactly? why do you need to be able to do this?

the question gives the impression that you have a lookAt matrix, but rather than just directly applying that matrix, you want to pull out the parameters just so you can pass them to gluLookAt?

I'm just interested to know why exactly you want to pull the parameters out of a lookAt matrix?

Comment: In this situation right now I am just applying the matrix, but the way I'm handling collision detection would make it easier if I just had coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the answer:
[how to convert modelview matrix to gluLookAt parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670461/how-to-convert-modelview-matrix-to-glulookat-parameters)

or

Pasted the same solution here:

From any 4x4 matrix we can get gluLookAt parameters which are CameraPos, CameraTarget, UpVector.
Here is the code to get CameraPos, CameraTarget, UpVector from ModelView matrix.

```
float modelViewMat[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelViewMat);

// Here instead of model view matrix we can pass any 4x4 matrix.
float params[9];
GetGluLookAtParameters(modelViewMat, params);

CameraPos.x = params[0];
CameraPos.y = params[1];
CameraPos.z = params[2];

CameraTarget.x = params[3];
CameraTarget.y = params[4];
CameraTarget.z = params[5];

UpVector.x = params[6];
UpVector.y = params[7];
UpVector.z = params[8];


void GetGluLookAtParameters(float* m, float* gluLookAtParams)
{
    VECTOR3D sideVector(m[0], m[4], m[8]);
    VECTOR3D upVector(m[1], m[5], m[9]);
    VECTOR3D forwardVector(-m[2], -m[6], -m[10]);

    sideVector.Normalize();
    upVector.Normalize();
    forwardVector.Normalize();

    float rotMat[16];
    memcpy(rotMat, m, 16*sizeof(float));
    rotMat[12] = rotMat[13] = rotMat[14] = rotMat[3] = rotMat[7] = rotMat[11] = 0.0f;
    rotMat[15] = 1.0f;
    float rotInvert[16];
    __gluInvertMatrixd(rotMat, rotInvert);

    float transMat[16];
    memset(transMat, 0, 16*sizeof(float));
    transMat[0] = transMat[5] = transMat[10] = transMat[15] = 1.0f;
    MultMat(rotInvert, m, transMat);

    gluLookAtParams[0] = -transMat[12];
    gluLookAtParams[1] = -transMat[13];
    gluLookAtParams[2] = -transMat[14];

    gluLookAtParams[3] = -transMat[12] + forwardVector.x;
    gluLookAtParams[4] = -transMat[13] + forwardVector.y;
    gluLookAtParams[5] = -transMat[14] + forwardVector.z;

    gluLookAtParams[6] = upVector.x;
    gluLookAtParams[7] = upVector.y;
    gluLookAtParams[8] = upVector.z;
}


void MultMat(float* a, float* b, float* result)
{
    result[0] = a[0]*b[0] + a[4]*b[1] + a[8]*b[2] + a[12]*b[3];
    result[1] = a[1]*b[0] + a[5]*b[1] + a[9]*b[2] + a[13]*b[3];
    result[2] = a[2]*b[0] + a[6]*b[1] + a[10]*b[2] + a[14]*b[3];
    result[3] = a[3]*b[0] + a[7]*b[1] + a[11]*b[2] + a[15]*b[3];

    result[4] = a[0]*b[4] + a[4]*b[5] + a[8]*b[6] + a[12]*b[7];
    result[5] = a[1]*b[4] + a[5]*b[5] + a[9]*b[6] + a[13]*b[7];
    result[6] = a[2]*b[4] + a[6]*b[5] + a[10]*b[6] + a[14]*b[7];
    result[7] = a[3]*b[4] + a[7]*b[5] + a[11]*b[6] + a[15]*b[7];

    result[8] = a[0]*b[8] + a[4]*b[9] + a[8]*b[10] + a[12]*b[11];
    result[9] = a[1]*b[8] + a[5]*b[9] + a[9]*b[10] + a[13]*b[11];
    result[10] = a[2]*b[8] + a[6]*b[9] + a[10]*b[10] + a[14]*b[11];
    result[11] = a[3]*b[8] + a[7]*b[9] + a[11]*b[10] + a[15]*b[11];

    result[12] = a[0]*b[12] + a[4]*b[13] + a[8]*b[14] + a[12]*b[15];
    result[13] = a[1]*b[12] + a[5]*b[13] + a[9]*b[14] + a[13]*b[15];
    result[14] = a[2]*b[12] + a[6]*b[13] + a[10]*b[14] + a[14]*b[15];
    result[15] = a[3]*b[12] + a[7]*b[13] + a[11]*b[14] + a[15]*b[15];
}


int __gluInvertMatrixd(const float src[16], float inverse[16])
{
    int i, j, k, swap;
    float t;
    GLfloat temp[4][4];

    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        for (j=0; j<4; j++)
            temp[i][j] = src[i*4+j];

    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
        inverse[i] = 0;
    inverse[0] = inverse[5] = inverse[10] = inverse[15] = 1.0f;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        swap = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < 4; j++)
            if (fabs(temp[j][i]) > fabs(temp[i][i]))
                swap = j;

        if (swap != i) {
            //Swap rows.
            for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                t = temp[i][k];
                temp[i][k] = temp[swap][k];
                temp[swap][k] = t;

                t = inverse[i*4+k];
                inverse[i*4+k] = inverse[swap*4+k];
                inverse[swap*4+k] = t;
            }
        }

        if (temp[i][i] == 0)
            return 0;

        t = temp[i][i];
        for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            temp[i][k] /= t;
            inverse[i*4+k] /= t;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                t = temp[j][i];
                for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                    temp[j][k] -= temp[i][k]*t;
                    inverse[j*4+k] -= inverse[i*4+k]*t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```